# UWP/C# Changing control visibility based on NavView Mode

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to try to change the visibility of my StackPanel based on the NavigationView "PaneDisplaymode"

I have the following Navigation View control with a simple AppBarButton StackPanel.

Im not sure if there is a way to reference the current PanDisplayMode and then determine the Visibility of the StackPanel?

Any guidance/help on this would be great.

```
<NavigationView IsSettingsVisible="False" 
                            PaneTitle="Menu"                            
                            x:Name="NavView"                             
                            IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" 
                            PaneDisplayMode="Left" 
                            AlwaysShowHeader="True"        
                            SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged">            

            <!-- All navigation view Items nested within here -->
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="False" x:Name="AppBarButtons" Tag="AppBarButtonPanel"> <!--Visibility="{Binding ControlShit}"-->
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Page2" Margin="0, 2, 1, 0" Tag="New_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="NewFile_ClickAsync"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="OpenFile" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Open_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="OpenFile_Click"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Save_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SaveButton_ClickAsync"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SettingsButton_Click"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Calculator" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Calculator_Open" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="CalcButton_ClickAsync"/>
                </StackPanel>
</NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PaneClosed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.paneclosed) and [PaneOpened](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.paneopened) events of **NavigationView** to change the **Visibility** of your **StackPanel** , another way to do it would be to use [DisplayModeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.displaymodechanged) where you can use a switch statement for **PaneDisplayMode** property and check whether it is closed or opened, and then change the visibility accordingly.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: You are Welcome :)